# Vector similarity with multiple dtypes (string, int, floats etc.)?

Tags: python-3.x, similarity

I have the following 2 rows in my dataframe:

```
[1, 1.1, -19, "kuku", "lulu"]
[2.8, 1.1, -20, "kuku", "lilu"]
```

I want to calculate their similarity by comparing each dimension (equal? 1, otherwise 0) and get the following vector: `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`, is there any function that takes a vector and performs such "similarity" against all rows and calculates mean? In our case it would be `2/5 = 0.4`.

Comment: If you want a Pandas solution, you should probably provide a minimal reproducible example at least for the inputs and outputs.

Comment: something like `df.corr()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a simple `=` on NumPy arrays, to be casted as `int` for the vector and `numpy.mean()` for the mean of the vector:

```
import numpy as np


a = [1, 1.1, -19, "kuku", "lulu"] 
b = [2.8, 1.1, -20, "kuku", "lilu"]


res = (np.array(a) == np.array(b)).astype(int)
print(res)                                                                                                                                             
# [0 1 0 1 0]
v = res.mean()
print(v)
# 0.4
```

---

If you do not mind computing everything twice and you can afford the potentially large intermediate temporary objects:

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.array([
    [1, 1.1, -19, "kuku", "lulu"],
    [2.8, 1.1, -20, "kuku", "lilu"],
    [2.8, 1.1, -20, "kuku", "lulu"]])


corr = arr[None, :, :] == arr[:, None, :]
score = corr.mean(-1)
print(score)
# [[1.  0.4 0.6]
#  [0.4 1.  0.8]
#  [0.6 0.8 1. ]]
```

Comment: I used exactly the same approach as you but I thought there is a function in pandas / sklearn for that like we have for cosine similarity.

Comment: @SteveS You can probably just mimic the above with Pandas (perhaps more efficiently), but you should provide some more details on the input/output you have/want.

Comment: I have a vector and dataframe (same columns) and I want to calc the similarity of the vector to each row (vector) in my dataframe, like I do it with cosine.